Is there a clang-tidy or fixit to use uniform initialization (aka brace initialization)?
We want initializations in our C++ code to use uniform initialization, e.g.:
bool b { true };

It would be great to have a tool helping us to modernize our code.
To my surprise, I only found modernize-return-braced-init-list which is about return statements.
Does no such tidy exist? Why?
Is there a way to tell one of the big compilers (Microsoft, CLANG / LLVM, gcc) to warn with a statement such as:
bool b = 5;

This is valid C++ but not possible with uniform initialization.

I would have assumed -Wall (GNU/clang) or /W4 (MSVC) would generate a warning for the bool b = 5; case...

Unfortunately it is only "almost uniform", so you cannot just change everything. For example vector<int> v {5} is different from vector<int> v(5). Don't know of a tool that handles this.

Local variables of built-in types are usually initialized using the latter. By some unwritten conventions.

Here is list of all checks https://godbolt.org/z/TqvdrhvjW I do not see anything about uniform initialization.

Voting to reopen: This isn't asking for recommendations for software, OP is aware of clang-tidy and fixit, it's asking for configuration help for those tools

Would you clarify in what situation you want a warning?  Are you asking for a warning/fix anytime an initialization does not use braces?  Or is the focus on getting a warning when a non-braced initializer uses a narrowing conversion, as in bool b = 5;?
